# Emulator: queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found

Tags: android, android-emulator

I get an error message when running avd.

Emulator: queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found

Comment: Please mention your OS and also share relevant logcat snippet.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue on Ubuntu 16.04, but the emulator comes up. also see 
    qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.abm [bit 5].

Comment: Same issue here, when I try to run emulator for Pixel 2 and Galaxy Nexus on Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Pro. Android Studio  v4.3.2.

Comment: @Clipr Art - Did you get any solution?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: same issue after updating android-studio.. anyone know how to solve this one - emulators are freezing and not working now

Comment: Have the same problem! any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Change the gpu mode in AVD configuration to `software`

`hw.gpu.mode = software`

Default is
`hw.gpu.mode = auto`

[See the highlighted line in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh4S1.png)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue  on Ubuntu 18.04 with AMD GPU driver 19.50 after upgrading to kernel 5.3.0-28-generic. Full error for me was:

```
Emulator: queryCoreProfileSupport: swap interval not found
Emulator: : CommandLine Error: Option 'help-list' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
```

Not a proper solution, but a **workaround** would be uninstalling the amdgpu[-pro] driver:

```
$/usr/bin/amdgpu-uninstall
```